# can we do HTTPS in c++ builder 6? installed INDY is only for HTTP requests

Tags: c++builder

Definitely someone was able to do https in c++ builder 6, can you share it please.

Please share a docs or code sample to do https in c++ builder 6.

The current http request code is working fine but the web service need to disable request via http, will only accept https request later.

Yes, Its a too old 32bit app.

Comment: There are many existing posts here about Indy and HTTPS, both for Delphi and C++ Builder. Have you done any research at all, or made any effort to search for them?

Comment: hi Ken White, most of i've seen are  c++ builder xe and ahead versions, i stopped looking after i've red a post that https is not supported in INDY 8, i remember https is only supported in INDY 10 and onwards?

Comment: As I mentioned, posts related to Delphi apply as well, as Indy is written In Delphi Pascal.

Comment: hi  ken White, would you be so kind to point, suggest a link or 1 thats successful compatible with bcb6 please. thanks

Comment: Asking us to provide links is off-topic, and I'm not your research assistant. You can do the searches yourself.

Comment: @Allan.A "*i stopped looking after i've red a post that https is not supported in INDY 8, i remember https is only supported in INDY 10 and onwards?*" - that is not true. Indy 8 and 9 supported HTTPS, too.

Comment: actually heres what  i  saw before, http://jeli23-unity.blogspot.com/2019/08/install-indy-10-to-c-builder-6.html, i just hesitated to try this, i might break the ancient ide.. :)

Comment: @Allan.A The very 1st sentence in that article is wrong: "*In C++ Builder 6, the default indy doesn't support SSL security.*" I have commented on the article. That said, upgrading to a *modern* Indy version would definitely be preferred, yes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indy's `TIdHTTP` definitely supports HTTPS, though you have to tell it which SSL/TLS library you want it to use, by linking an appropriate `SSL` component to `TIdHTTP` before connecting to a server.

Which component to use depends on which version of Indy you are using, which you have not stated. I forget whether C++Builder 6 shipped with Indy 8 or 9. But you really should upgrade to the latest Indy 10, which still supports C++Builder 6 <sup>(1)</sup>.

In Indy 8, assign a `TIdConnectionInterceptOpenSSL` component to the `TIdHTTP::Intercept` property.

In Indy 9, assign a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocket` component to the `TIdHTTP::IOHandler` property.

In Indy 10, assign a `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase`-derived component to the `TIdHTTP::IOHandler` property <sup>(2)</sup>. The default SSL component is `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL` <sup>(3)</sup>.

The default SSL components are all wrappers for OpenSSL, so you will also need to deploy the 2 OpenSSL DLLs with your app - `ssleay32.dll` and `libeay32.dll`, which you can download from [Indy's OpenSSL Binaries repo](https://github.com/IndySockets/OpenSSL-Binaries). Indy 8 and 9 require a customized version of OpenSSL, so they will only work with the `indy_openssl096?.zip` DLLs in the `Archive` folder. Indy 10's `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketOpenSSL`will work with official DLLs up to 1.0.2u. For OpenSSL 1.1.x, use [this SSLIOHandler](https://github.com/IndySockets/Indy/pull/299) component instead (WIP).

(1): support for pre-2009 versions of C++Builder and Delphi will be dropped in Indy 11.

(2): [modern Indy 10 can handle this for you](https://www.indyproject.org/2014/12/22/new-https-functionality-for-tidhttp/).

(3): If you want to use a different TLS library, you will have to wrap it inside of a custom component that is derived from `TIdSSLIOHandlerSocketBase` and overrides a few virtual methods to delegate read/write operations to the library.

Comment: will try this one,  thanks Remy Lebeau